# Make a Registration Bot with Telegram Bot API

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a bot that register an user on my website.
This bot should ask some key informations about the user like:

- First Name
- Last Name
- Username
- Email Address
- Profile Link

In your opinion what is the best method to implement this feature?
I've seen somebody suggesting to use database in order to find out what message you've sent to user, and what information you have for the user and ask the missing one accordingly! 
This particular way to solve this problem, could be effective but not so much efficient imho! Is there any way at all to use like a callback query or maybe give a message an specific id, so I can check whether the last message id is the "username_request" and respond accordingly?

Let me know

Oh by the way, I'm using PHP and the Webhook method!

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks - there are solution. 
 You need to install **shapoapps/multibot_driver** (composer require shapoapps/multibot_driver) for Laravel.
In this packet there are session manager. Its like sessions for web browser users. But only for messenger users (telegram, ...). 
After each user message received, you can record user input into the session on server side. When each new request(message) received, you read the data from the session and build the application logic.
Here's the documentation - https://github.com/shapoapps/multibot_driver

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on a similar project at the moment.

I was thinking about some kind of syntax wherein you place the things you want to save, for example:

```
John,,,Hawk,,,JHawk,,,jhawk@gmail.com,,,https://www.url.com/
```

After saying

> /adduser
>   John,,,Hawk,,,JHawk,,,jhawk@gmail.com,,,https://www.url.com/

inside the chat: you can split the message at the three commas (,,,) with PHP.

Otherwise you could:

- Make some kind of transaction protocol to let the bot ask values per item after saying

> /adduser

inside the Telegram chat.

Let me know how you think about these ways! Typing the three commas (,,,) once is not so much effort, but if you have to add multiple users a day... It could become very annoying..

Comment: What you said suggest that I need to add user in the text field of the bot, and that's it! Well I actually want the user to interact with the bot and fill up all the answers! 
I want the bot ask like: "Hey you are you new here? you want to sign up?" with an InlineKeyboard with "yes" "no"
Then after the user press yes, the bot ask for his/her first name and so on!